# Asp. Net Web Form after a while become unresponsive

Tags: mysql, asp.net, webforms

can someone help me with my web form application why it become unresponsive. I will try to explain  the situation. My application generate file with QR codes, after i choose path where to generate file and  click button Print file is generate and i get message 'You generate file successfully' then update my MySQL database.

```
dbConnection()
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO`tblPrintedFiles`(`fldBatchID`,`fldDate`,`fldText`,`fldPrintedPath`,`fldPrinter`) VALUES ('" & batch & "',NOW(),'" & SQLText(strLog) & "','" & strName.Replace("\", "/") & "','" & printer & " ');"
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Dispose()
```

I didn't close the site, but after a several time (for example 8-10 minutes) i choose a new path from 'DropDownList' and it generate a file but doesn't do a update in my database. And 
I use IIS Manager 8.5, this is my first web form application :)

Comment: Example for inserting data ```var db = Database.Open("WebPagesMovies");
var insertCommand = "INSERT INTO Movies (Title, Genre, Year) VALUES(@0, @1, @2)";
db.Execute(insertCommand, title, genre, year);```  from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-aspnet-web-pages-2/entering-data

Comment: Your posted code does not compile. Your code does not show the view code, or the backend code and how you call the code that you have posted.

Comment: @kpollock that is sql server. OP is using MySQL.

Comment: I doesn't post view code or back end code because they are very large.The view is 400 rows, back end is 700 rows

Comment: The problem is after a while site can't go in other pages. I  can click a button but it doesn't update my database

Comment: ah sorry .......